# PayPal order review page redirect

Tags: checkout

I'm trying to setup PayPal express checkout to bypass redirect to Magento review page.
I have followed directions posted on stackoverflow link below but I am still redirected to http://mysite.com/index.php/paypal/express/review/   review page the button has changed to pay now but I am redirected before I can complete checkout.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607180/magento-easy-way-to-remove-paypal-express-review-step/14313748#14313748

Anybody point me in the right direction?

Changed
 \app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Controller\Express\Abstract.php

returnAction() for:
$this->_redirect('*/*/review');

changed:
$this->_redirect('*/*/review');

to:
$this->_redirect('*/*/placeOrder');
 Go to: \app\code\core\Mage\Paypal\Controller\Express\Abstract.php

and search in returnAction() for:
$this->_redirect('*/*/review');

There you have to change:
$this->_redirect('*/*/review');

Answer (score 3):

Actually all the solutions mentioned here required to edit the Magento core. This is known as **bad practise** and does not keep your shop updateable.

What you need to do for a **clean solution**:

1. Create a module (in my exampe: Avoe_Paypal) to include the changes
2. Rewrite Paypal Config
3. Redirect on paypal express review step which is http://yourdomain.com/paypal/express/review/

**1) Create your module**

Avoe/Paypal/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Avoe_Paypal>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Avoe_Paypal>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <Avoe_Paypal>
                <class>Avoe_Paypal_Model</class>
            </Avoe_Paypal>
            <paypal>
                <rewrite>
                    <config>Avoe_Paypal_Model_Config</config>
                </rewrite>
            </paypal>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_paypal_express_review>
                <observers>
                    <avoe_paypal_predispatch>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Avoe_Paypal_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>paypalExpressReturnPredispatch</method>
                    </avoe_paypal_predispatch>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_paypal_express_review>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/etc/Avoe_Paypal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Avoe_Paypal>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Paypal />
            </depends>
        </Avoe_Paypal>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**2) Rewrite config, add useraction 'commit':**

```
<?php
class Avoe_Paypal_Model_Config extends Mage_Paypal_Model_Config {

    /**
     * Get url for dispatching customer to express checkout start
     * Added useraction 'commit' to remove PayPal Express Checkout review page
     *
     * @param string $token
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExpressCheckoutStartUrl($token)
    {
        return $this->getPaypalUrl(array(
            'cmd'   => '_express-checkout',
            'useraction' => 'commit',
            'token' => $token,
        ));
    }
}
```

**3) Create observer to redirect:**

```
<?php

class Avoe_Paypal_Model_Observer {

    function paypalExpressReturnPredispatch($observer) {
        Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('*/*/placeOrder'));
    }
}
```

There is also a small Magento extension which was just released yesterday, to remove the review step:

https://github.com/tim-bezhashvyly/Sandfox_RemovePaypalExpressReviewStep

Comment: Please note that Paypal Express Checkout is a checkout method not a payment method, thus customers by default will always be redirected to the order review page since this is the default flow of events.

Answer (score 0):

In the PayPal configuration, expand the "Advanced Settings" and look for the option "Skip Order Review Step". Change that to "Yes" instead of "No".